# Show that the E(|X|) is finite.

Tags: probability, expectation

Show that if $E(X^2)<\infty$ then $E(|X|)<\infty$.

My try:

In other word, if
$$\int x^2f(x)dx<\infty\Rightarrow\int xf(x)dx<\infty$$
for continuous case which $\int f(x)dx=1$

or
$$\sum x^2f(x)dx<\infty\Rightarrow\sum xf(x)dx<\infty$$
for discrete case which $\sum f(x)dx=1$

then I get stuck already because I can't continue.

And I found similar question on this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247041/showing-ex-is-finite) but I not really understand their answer, is there any simple way to solve this problem? I appreciate your help.

Comment: if $E(X)=\pm \infty$ then $Var(X)=-\infty$ but $0 \leq Var(X)$?

Comment: I leave a question mark because I'm not entirely sure this is sound logic. I think it is though, and it's at least very quick

Comment: $p\rightarrow(q \cap r)$ but $q$ is false because $Var(X)$ cannot be negative therefore whole statement is false. May I know what are you trying to show me?

Comment: "Show that if $E(X^2)<\infty$ then $E(|X|)<\infty$", obviously

Comment: I just assumed $E(|X|)=\infty$ and got a contradiction, it's a really easy proof structure

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$0 \leq |X| < 1+X^2~ \Rightarrow ~ 0 \leq E[|X|] < 1 + E[X^2] < \infty$.

Comment: Aaaaah... +1. $ $

Answer (score 5):

$$\int x f(x)\,dx=\int x \sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{f(x)}\,dx\leqslant\left(\int x^2f(x)\,dx\right)^\frac12\left(\int f(x)\,dx\right)^\frac12$$
by Cauchy inequality.

Comment: Sorry, can you tell me what are you trying to do? Are you try bound it to show it is finite?

Comment: you could also go with $\int x f(x)\,dx=\int x \sqrt{f(x)}\sqrt{f(x)}\,dx\leq\frac{1}{2}\left(\int x^2f(x)\,dx+\int f(x)\,dx\right)$ since $ab\leq \frac{a^2+b^2}{2}$

Comment: @EdwardSiew, sure: if the right side is finite then so is the left side too.

Answer (score 3):

Since $h(z)=z^2$ is a convex function, by Jensen's inequality:

$$h(E(|X|)) \le E(h(|X|))\\
\Rightarrow (E(|X|))^2 \le E(|X|^2) <\infty \\
\Rightarrow  E(|X|) < \infty
$$

Another way to intuitively think of this is this: Consider the random variable $|X|$. Then:
$$
0 \le V(|X|)\\
\Rightarrow 0 \le E|X^2|-(E(|X|))^2 \\
\Rightarrow (E(|X|))^2 \le E|X^2| = E(X^2) < \infty \\
\Rightarrow E(|X|) < \infty
$$